# Running Meteor Up how to choose settings file

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using Meteor Up to deploy my app to production server.

For now I am configuring Meteor.settings through settings-dev.json and settings-prod.json for development and production environments.

I have two main doubts:

How can I run 'mup deploy' command from my machine and choose settings-prod.json?

Is this the best practice to configure my server and resource values using settings-[env].json to deploy my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just use the default name `/settings.json`. It will work. When you execute `mup init` it will automatically create 2 files.

- `mup.json` - Meteor Up configuration file
- `settings.json` - Settings for Meteor's [settings API](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings)

And yes it is a good idea to use `settings.json`. Just be careful to not insert any secret information inside `"public": {}`

For example:

```
{
  "public": {
     "publicKey": 'xxx' // available to the client
   },
   "oauthSecretKey": "xxx" // available to server only
}
```

Comment: thanks! and about mup deploy, how can deploy with a specific settings file like settings-prod.json?

Comment: @rodrigocprates reading the docs it doesn't say how to specify custom settings file but it does say if you're looking for production and staging it should be separated folders (that's how I do it too) https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#server-configuration

Comment: it's fine! creating a separated folder solve this issue. thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @MarkUretsky your link is dead. I need to deploy to different server environments depending on the git branch. How do you do this?

Comment: @AdamMendoze it's `mup deploy --settings my_settings.json` or whatever your settings json is called.